# How to refactor global constants into a module - JS best practices

Tags: javascript, jasmine, global-variables, refactoring, constants

I'm new to JS - my reading so far suggests that global variables are a huge red flag and should be avoided at all costs. I'm currently working on a refactoring challenge and I have some numerical values declared in a .js file which are subsequently called upon in other .js files in the program. I'm unsure on the best practices to utilise here and therefore to eliminate any code smells.

I have some constants stored in a file, `options.js`. These constants are then used in several other files such as `agedbrie.js`, and `quality.js`.

All of these files are stored within one folder.

In terms of steps undertaken so far, I've considered simply declaring the required variables within each function which needs them, therefore (I think) removing them from the global space. However this leads to a fair amount of repetition, and leads to code which isn't following DRY principles.

Options.js:

```
 const MIN_SALE_DATE = 0
 const MAX_QUALITY = 50
 const MIN_QUALITY = 0
 const SULFURAS_QUALITY = 80
```

Examples of where these constants are called in other files in my program:

Agedbrie.js

```
(function(exports){

//other code unrelated
}

AgedBrie.prototype.updateQuality = function () {
    if (this.sellIn > MIN_SALE_DATE ){
```

quality.js:

```
    //other code 

function qualityMaximum(quality){
    if (quality > MAX_QUALITY) {
        quality = MAX_QUALITY
    }
    return quality
}
    //further code
```

In essence I have code which works right now and passes tests I have written, however I'm keen to pick up best practices early, therefore eliminating any possible global variables is pretty important. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify - This is an attempt at the [Gilded Rose Kata](https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata/tree/master/js-jasmine)

I have a working solution, only it contains global variables at present which I know are a bit of a red flag when it comes to best practices.

**EDIT 2**

I managed to rectify this myself - if anyone else gets here through Google, here is what I did:

options.js

```
var OPTIONS = (function() {

  var private = {
    "MIN_SALE_DATE" : 0,
    "MAX_QUALITY" : 50,
    "MIN_QUALITY" : 0,
    "SULFURAS_QUALITY" : 80
    };

  return {
    get: function(name) { return private[name]; }
  };

})();
```

Then in order to call on these variables elsewhere in my code:

```
OPTIONS.get("name here")
```

Comment: To avoid making *anything* global, you'll have to have *all* scripts compiled together into one, possibly with a bundler like Webpack

Comment: is this backend project or frontend?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer; the project is purely refactoring - namely the Gilded Rose - https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata/tree/master/js-jasmine

Like I said, I have a solution which is working, only I'm concerned about possible global variables use

Comment: Your `var OPTIONS` is still polluting the global scope, though. To avoid that, you'll have to put *all* the scripts into a single file (possibly with the help of a bundler, as mentioned) and use an IIFE.